# Dell integrated Webcam does not function

Tags: webcam, dell-xps

I have a Windows 8 Dell workstation XPS 8700 (Mid 2013) and recently purchased the Dell multimedia monitor UZ2315H 23 inch LCD Monitor. Issue is I can’t get the webcam integrated into the monitor to function.

- Connected the monitor to the PC via both HDMI and USB cables (at the same time).
- Re-booted.
- Get message saying installing drivers.
- Also installed all drivers from CD that accompanied the monitor.
- Installed “Dell display manager” from CD that accompanied the monitor.
- Perform a test via Skype, the microphone integrated into the monitor works.
- Perform a test via Skype and no webcam is found.
- Navigate to Device Manager and “imaging devices” does not appear in the list.

What can I do to get the PC to recognise the webcam? All the other functionality of the monitor is fine (display, sound, microphone).

Comment: Have you downloaded the drivers from the website?  You should try [that](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=1K8M6) the drivers on the disk are likely extremely old.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a hiccup.  It is no longer reproducible, there is no longer a problem to solve, and there is no way to determine the value of any potential answer.

Comment: Apparently there are known problems with built-in webcams in Dell monitors under Windows 10 and drivers are not being updated.

Answer (score 1):

If your device is not recognized it won't be on the imaging devices tree list but probably on the unknown list with the yellow question mark. Try identifying your Webcam through that and do a re-installation of your drivers. It could be the case that the drivers are incompatible with the version of the OS you are using. Try searching more drivers on the dell website for other versions of OS.

Lastly, try unknown device identifier software by HunterSoft, in the case that you can't find your webcam.

I hope you resolve it. - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got home from work to try these suggestions and the issue had fixed itself. I did no further actions, not even a reboot, so can't add a fix here. Imaging devices now appears in  device manager but it didn't after the initial reboot.

[image]

Comment: This is not really an answer, but should be integrated into your original question.